# php search and add content after

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, search

In my content I have a 'shortcode' to display videos with different parameters depending on how I want the video to look. For example: height, width, video, etc.

What can I write in php to search for `[video {paramaters}]` and add content after it?

Keep in mind `{parameters}` will always be different.

Comment: Theres really no more code than this... lets say i set $after_content = 'text after content'; Now i need to find this code `[video webkit="video.m4v" width="500" height="210"]` add it to a variable and add $after_content after the video. i just dont know how to search for code in the content

Comment: Am I right in guessing this is a WordPress plugin you're trying to modify?

Comment: @stealthyninja: you are correct it is with wordpress, but its not a plugin. i made the shortcode, how ever there needs to be a copyright under the video, but only on certain pages. so i assume the easiest way is instead of using `the_content` ill do a little search for the video code add my text after it and then use `apply_filter('the_content', get_the_content)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when I need to do something like this i use preg_replace or preg_replace_callback..

```
function videofunction($input){

//do something here and then:
return $whatever;

}

$content =  preg_replace('%\[video(.*?)\]%e', 'videofunction("\\1")', $content);
```

You then have to come up with the logic though =)

Edit:
Just read your post more...
You want to leave the tag as is, and add something after it..
You could do this with preg replace.. like this:

```
function videofunction($input){

$input .= "whatever else";
return $input;
}

preg_replace('%\[video.*?\]%e', 'videofunction("\\0")', $content);
```

Probably not the best way to do it though, maybe some kind of offset capture would be better?

Comment: Very nice, that worked! Thanks. Can you explain to me whats going on tho. I have never seen `function_name('\\0')`. What exactly is the '\\0' doing?

Comment: Basically it is a backreference to what was captured.  In the first example I gave it had a \\1 because I wanted to capture what was inside the parentheses .  If you have a regex like: (cap1) (cap2) (cap3). you can use the backreferences like cap1(\\0)  cap2(\\1)  so on and so forth.  also check out preg_replace_callback. it is a bit cleaner