# PHP search content for ID and add Class

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I need a simple function that will search my wordpress content for a specific ID, and than add a class to the same element the ID is in.

Its for a video player plugin that displays itself via shortcode. My problem is the plugin gives each element an ID as follows, `id="video-1-player", id="video-2-player"`. So the function needs to search the content for `id="video-(any number)-player"` and than insert a class in there.

thanks!

EDIT

heres the answer that worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180884/278629

Comment: Do you need it during page rendering or do you want to walk through the DB adding class to matching ID ?

Comment: I need it for the page, not the DB.

Comment: Is there a reason you need it to have a class instead of just referring to their ids?  If you can't edit the php source-code that rights the video player, you're likely going to have to use jquery like mentioned below.

Comment: It can't be in Javascript. It must be in PHP. And i need to add a specific class to all of them for CSS reasons. Not an individual ID.

Comment: Then you need to modify the code of the plugin. Search the line where it outputs the id and modify it to add your class attribute.

Comment: @Carlos - That also dosnt work due to the plugin getting updates often... I have seen very similar functions like this but my PHP isnt good enough to modify them to my needs. If you want i can send you the function. It looks for the first image and stores it in a variable. Its not to far away from what im looking for. Anyone who knows PHP should be able to do this without a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class to represent your document as an object. Query for the ID you're seeking, and add a class onto it. From there you can spit the HTML back out.

Simple example:

```php
// HTML to be handled (could very well be read in)
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p id='foo'>Foo</p></body></html>";

// Create and load our DOMDocument object
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

// Find and manipulate our paragraph
$foo = $doc->getElementById("foo");
$foo->setAttribute("class", "bar");

// Return the entire document HTML
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Alternatively, if you only wanted the HTML for the affected element:

```php
echo $doc->saveHTML($foo);
```

The generated HTML follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="foo" class="bar">Foo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that the above code doesn't first check to see if the class attribute is already present on the element. You should perform that check so as to not lose any pre-existing classes that might already be on the element.

Comment: i edited my question with the answer that worked for me. but it does look like yours would also work, so ill give it to ya. thanks any ways